# My account cannot drag tasks in the taskboard of Azure Devops. How do I fix this?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

My account isn't able to perform basic tasks, like dragging the tasks between the columns new-active-closed in boards. I am able to switch the tasks when I manually open the task and change the status. But I want to be able to drag them, like everyone else.

Also, when I want to add use stories and tasks to my features in Backlogs, I am not able to use the + sign next to the epics and features. I have to add them in the boards and manually link them to the respective parents and childs.

Does anyone know why I am not able to perform basic tasks like these?

Answer (score 3):

You can check your access level in your organization. Likely you're in stakeholder access level, so you are unable to drag-drop the cards in Boards or Taskboard.

Answer (score 0):

> My account cannot drag tasks in the taskboard of Azure Devops.

For this issue , if your access level is **Stakeholder**, then you cannot drag and drop work items in boards. Stakeholders can change work item status to move an item across the board. However, dragging and dropping to achieve the same result is not supported for stakeholders. Currently this is by design.

One of the reasons why this limitation exists is because drag-n-drop of the item on Kanban board does change the order of the item, which means reprioritizes the backlog. When you drag-n-drop on the board, you place the item in specific place in between other items and change the stack rank. Since Stakeholder license does not allow re-prioritization of the backlog, drag-n-drop is not allowed for them.

The limitation of Stakeholder license also applied to other functionality in the product, including deleting work items and full access to Dashboards. You can find list of features that are not available for Stakeholders [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/get-started-stakeholder?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process#features).

Until now, in our official feature suggestion for Azure Devops forum, there has been a such suggestion exist in it: [Allow stakeholders to drag and drop work items](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365539/allow-stakeholders-to-drag-and-drop-work-items.html). You can comment and vote it there.

> I am not able to use the + sign next to the epics and features.

For this issue , this is also due to the limitation of Stakeholder access level.